# XSLT - convert overly nested XML to a HTML table, how to reference elements in a loop

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm receiving this xml (actually this is a converted EDI/EDIFACT message):

```xml
<EDIFACT>
<SLSFCT>
    <DTM>
        <DTM01>
            <DTM0101 decode="Date, as at">
                <!--2005: Date/time/period qualifier-->183</DTM0101>
            <DTM0102>
                <!--2380: Date/time/period-->140112</DTM0102>
            <DTM0103 decode="DDMMYY">
                <!--2379: Date/time/period format qualifier-->2</DTM0103>
        </DTM01>
    </DTM>
    <GROUP_5>
        <DTM>
            <DTM01>
                <DTM0101 decode="Horizon period">
                    <!--2005: Date/time/period qualifier-->323</DTM0101>
                <DTM0102>
                    <!--2380: Date/time/period-->0112</DTM0102>
                <DTM0103 decode="YYMM">
                    <!--2379: Date/time/period format qualifier-->609</DTM0103>
            </DTM01>
        </DTM>
        <GROUP_6>
            <LIN>
                <LIN01>
                    <!--1082: LINE ITEM NUMBER-->1</LIN01>
                <LIN03>
                    <LIN0301>
                        <!--7140: Item number-->88840</LIN0301>
                    <LIN0302 decode="Buyer's item number">
                        <!--7143: Item number type, coded-->IN</LIN0302>
                    <LIN0304 decode="Assigned by buyer or buyer's agent">
                        <!--3055: Code list responsible agency, coded-->92</LIN0304>
                </LIN03>
            </LIN>
            <PIA>
                <PIA01 decode="Additional identification">
                    <!--4347: PRODUCT ID. FUNCTION QUALIFIER-->1</PIA01>
                <PIA03>
                    <PIA0301>
                        <!--7140: Item number-->0</PIA0301>
                    <PIA0302 decode="Supplier's article number">
                        <!--7143: Item number type, coded-->SA</PIA0302>
                    <PIA0304 decode="Assigned by seller or seller's agent">
                        <!--3055: Code list responsible agency, coded-->91</PIA0304>
                </PIA03>
            </PIA>
            <GROUP_7>
                <QTY>
                    <QTY01>
                        <QTY0101 decode="Cumulative quantity, actual estimated">
                            <!--6063: Quantity qualifier-->138</QTY0101>
                        <QTY0102>
                            <!--6060: Quantity-->10</QTY0102>
                        <QTY0103>
                            <!--6411: Measure unit qualifier-->PCE</QTY0103>
                    </QTY01>
                </QTY>
            </GROUP_7>
        </GROUP_6>
        <GROUP_6>
            <LIN>
                <LIN01>
                    <!--1082: LINE ITEM NUMBER-->1</LIN01>
                <LIN03>
                    <LIN0301>
                        <!--7140: Item number-->884530</LIN0301>
                    <LIN0302 decode="Buyer's item number">
                        <!--7143: Item number type, coded-->IN</LIN0302>
                    <LIN0304 decode="Assigned by buyer or buyer's agent">
                        <!--3055: Code list responsible agency, coded-->92</LIN0304>
                </LIN03>
            </LIN>
            <PIA>
                <PIA01 decode="Additional identification">
                    <!--4347: PRODUCT ID. FUNCTION QUALIFIER-->1</PIA01>
                <PIA03>
                    <PIA0301>
                        <!--7140: Item number-->8888774319981</PIA0301>
                    <PIA0302 decode="Supplier's article number">
                        <!--7143: Item number type, coded-->SA</PIA0302>
                    <PIA0304 decode="Assigned by seller or seller's agent">
                        <!--3055: Code list responsible agency, coded-->91</PIA0304>
                </PIA03>
            </PIA>
            <GROUP_7>
                <QTY>
                    <QTY01>
                        <QTY0101 decode="Cumulative quantity, actual estimated">
                            <!--6063: Quantity qualifier-->138</QTY0101>
                        <QTY0102>
                            <!--6060: Quantity-->15</QTY0102>
                        <QTY0103>
                            <!--6411: Measure unit qualifier-->PCE</QTY0103>
                    </QTY01>
                </QTY>
            </GROUP_7>
        </GROUP_6>
    </GROUP_5>
    <GROUP_5>
        <DTM>
            <DTM01>
                <DTM0101 decode="Horizon period">
                    <!--2005: Date/time/period qualifier-->323</DTM0101>
                <DTM0102>
                    <!--2380: Date/time/period-->0212</DTM0102>
                <DTM0103 decode="YYMM">
                    <!--2379: Date/time/period format qualifier-->609</DTM0103>
            </DTM01>
        </DTM>
        <GROUP_6>
            <LIN>
                <LIN01>
                    <!--1082: LINE ITEM NUMBER-->1</LIN01>
                <LIN03>
                    <LIN0301>
                        <!--7140: Item number-->188840</LIN0301>
                    <LIN0302 decode="Buyer's item number">
                        <!--7143: Item number type, coded-->IN</LIN0302>
                    <LIN0304 decode="Assigned by buyer or buyer's agent">
                        <!--3055: Code list responsible agency, coded-->92</LIN0304>
                </LIN03>
            </LIN>
            <PIA>
                <PIA01 decode="Additional identification">
                    <!--4347: PRODUCT ID. FUNCTION QUALIFIER-->1</PIA01>
                <PIA03>
                    <PIA0301>
                        <!--7140: Item number-->0</PIA0301>
                    <PIA0302 decode="Supplier's article number">
                        <!--7143: Item number type, coded-->SA</PIA0302>
                    <PIA0304 decode="Assigned by seller or seller's agent">
                        <!--3055: Code list responsible agency, coded-->91</PIA0304>
                </PIA03>
            </PIA>
            <GROUP_7>
                <QTY>
                    <QTY01>
                        <QTY0101 decode="Cumulative quantity, actual estimated">
                            <!--6063: Quantity qualifier-->138</QTY0101>
                        <QTY0102>
                            <!--6060: Quantity-->20</QTY0102>
                        <QTY0103>
                            <!--6411: Measure unit qualifier-->PCE</QTY0103>
                    </QTY01>
                </QTY>
            </GROUP_7>
        </GROUP_6>
        <GROUP_6>
            <LIN>
                <LIN01>
                    <!--1082: LINE ITEM NUMBER-->1</LIN01>
                <LIN03>
                    <LIN0301>
                        <!--7140: Item number-->16880</LIN0301>
                    <LIN0302 decode="Buyer's item number">
                        <!--7143: Item number type, coded-->IN</LIN0302>
                    <LIN0304 decode="Assigned by buyer or buyer's agent">
                        <!--3055: Code list responsible agency, coded-->92</LIN0304>
                </LIN03>
            </LIN>
            <PIA>
                <PIA01 decode="Additional identification">
                    <!--4347: PRODUCT ID. FUNCTION QUALIFIER-->1</PIA01>
                <PIA03>
                    <PIA0301>
                        <!--7140: Item number-->4088888319981</PIA0301>
                    <PIA0302 decode="Supplier's article number">
                        <!--7143: Item number type, coded-->SA</PIA0302>
                    <PIA0304 decode="Assigned by seller or seller's agent">
                        <!--3055: Code list responsible agency, coded-->91</PIA0304>
                </PIA03>
            </PIA>
            <GROUP_7>
                <QTY>
                    <QTY01>
                        <QTY0101 decode="Cumulative quantity, actual estimated">
                            <!--6063: Quantity qualifier-->138</QTY0101>
                        <QTY0102>
                            <!--6060: Quantity-->25</QTY0102>
                        <QTY0103>
                            <!--6411: Measure unit qualifier-->PCE</QTY0103>
                    </QTY01>
                </QTY>
            </GROUP_7>
        </GROUP_6>
    </GROUP_5>
</SLSFCT>
```

and I'm trying to convert it to a readable HTML table. The data in the XML is actually a sales forecast and it's structure is like that:

```
SLSFCT
  +
  |
  +-+GROUP_5
     +   +
     |   +->MONTH
     |
     +-+GROUP_6
        +   +
        |   +->ARTICLE/ITEM NUMBER
        |
        +-+GROUP_7
            +
            +->EXPECTED QTY
```

I would like to achive an output like this:

```
ITEM# JAN FEB MAY
32815   1   6  12
48015  10  21  89
```

So far I got this humble approach:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/EDIFACT/SLSFCT">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>Artikel</td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="GROUP_5/DTM">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="DTM01/DTM0102"/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="GROUP_5/GROUP_6">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="LIN/LIN03/LIN0301"/>
                        </td>
                        <xsl:for-each select="../../GROUP_5">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="GROUP_6/GROUP_7/QTY/QTY01/QTY0102"/>
                            </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

But I'm having a hard time to get the right values from `GROUP_6/GROUP_7/QTY/QTY01/QTY0102` , it seems like it's getting always the same values. Getting the months and article numbers is working fine though, just the expected sales figures (QTY0102) are wrong.

I also played around with `position()` etc. but I can't wrap my head around this :-/

So, anyone here to point me in the right direction ? Dimitre ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<xsl:for-each select="../GROUP_6">
  <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="GROUP_7/QTY/QTY01/QTY0102"/>
  </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

as your inner for-each-loop. the code you've posted iterates over **all** `group5` elements on every article number, this doesn't appear to be what you're aiming at.

regards